# how does react diff algorithm find out this assumption?

Tags: reactjs, web, diff

I am using react to build my own web app, but I am wondering how does the following  assumption make react diff faster. In other words, what does react base this assumption on?

> Two elements of different types will produce different trees.

Comment: You can refer [https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html] for further understanding.

Comment: I've read this doc, but it only shows what react will do based on this assumption. I wanna know the reason why react make this assumption. @MayankBansal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That assumption enables React to find out minimum number of operations to transform one DOM tree into another one in O(n) time.

> However, the state of the art algorithms have a complexity in the order of O(n3) where n is the number of elements in the tree. If we used this in React, displaying 1000 elements would require in the order of one billion comparisons. This is far too expensive.

By assuming that elements of different types have different trees, react will save valuable computation time by avoiding too many comparisons to convert one tree into another. So without this if you have the following structure

```
<div>
    <span> </span>
    <span> </span>
</div>
```

and if your new structure is

```
<span>
    <span> </span>
    <div> </div>
</span>
```

React will now have to compare whether the first span child was there or not. Then it will have to compare whether second child div is there or not; now it finds that it wasn't there so it will have to only change the second div along with the outer parent tag. (Imagine doing this for 1000 elements)

They have also mentioned

> In practice, these assumptions are valid for almost all practical use cases.

And from my experience in almost all cases it is always true.

Answer (score 0):

React creates and keeps an exactly same copy of actual DOM which is termed as virtual DOM. This will have everything the actual DOM has like objects and their types and their values. Whenever there is any change in the actual DOM, react takes a snapshot of it right before the update and compares it with the virtual DOM, and based on the differences found it goes and updates the actual DOM.

So if you have two elements of different types, there will be a different tree.

This is my understanding, let me know if you find something else.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.    I am sorry I cant agree with you.  Any change in the actual DOM will be the last step of reconciliation process. Reconciliation will determin whether update the actual DOM after comparing old and new virtual dom which is created after executing the render method.

Answer (score 0):

Diffing Algorithm Assumptions

1. If two react elements have a different type, the algorithm assumes their content to be different. 
    
   **Note:** If two react elements have the same content but different types, the diffing algorithm takes the content differently and unnecessary modification will be done in the real DOM.

   Try out this by creating two-component, render one of them in the first render and render the other in the future render. If you inspect the element in the developer tool you will see unnecessary modification is made in the real DOM. 
   https://codesandbox.io/s/diffing-algorithm-assumptions-7gsxxw
2. We are providing a key as a prop to every element in case we are rendering a list of items.